# Parsing a variable through a URL in HTML

Tags: c#, html, sql, parsing, url

I have parsed two variables through a URL in HTML using the following method in a HTML page as a link to another HTML page:

```
<a href="Customer.cshtml? seat_row = @item.Seat_Row ? seat_number =@item.Seat_No"></a>
```

The two variables are seat_row and seat_number.

I would now like to display these in the customer.cshtml inside paragraph tags.

Upon running the URL displays

```
"http://localhost:2368/Customer.cshtml? seat_row = A ? seat_number =2"
```

So I can see the variables are parsing, however I do not know how to display this on the actual page?

Thanks

Comment: `What do you mean when you say do not how to display` are you wanting the `URI` to be displayed in a label or something.? please clarify as well as clean up your question

Comment: @DJKRAZE I do not know how to display the parsed variables from the URL on the actual page. So in this case, how do I display the seat_row variable as part of a sentence - sorry is that better explained? Previously I tried using the QueryString method

Comment: are you familiar with the `Split` function use it similar to how you would split a norm string or `strings` but in your case you can split the current url something like this `var myParams = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Split("?");`

Comment: Your URL is malformed. Query-string variables should be separated with an `&`, not another `?`. You also have too much white-space within the query-string. It should look like `?seat_row=A&seat_number=2`.

Comment: @RichardDeeming you genius! thank you so much